# Flagging components of a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

So basically, I have two excel tables that I want to compare. I wrote a =EXACT formula, and flagged all of the ones that are false as red. But now, I want to also flag the cells that they are comparing as red too.

So for example, I'll have =EXACT(A1, D1), where A1 is dog and D1 is Cat. This will make the EXACT scale red. How do I make cells A1 and D1 red as well?

Comment: A coworker ended up showing me how to do it using Conditional Formatting. If you are curious, you just use a formula and apply it to each column (kinda like what guitarthrower was suggesting)

Answer (score 0):

If to be repeated down a column and assuming your current formula is in G1, try:

```
=$A1<>$D1
```

for Format values where this formula is true: under Use a formula to determine which cells to format and Applies to

```
=$A:$A,$D:$D,$G:$G
```

Comment: Can you clarify please? I don't think I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

Formulas can only affect the cell they're in. You can't use a formula in one cell to change the formatting (or value) of a different cell.

One option is to write a macro, since macros can access all the cells on a worksheet and change their values or formats.

Comment: A macro, or conditional formatting. Although it doesn't sound like conditional formatting would suit the OPs needs.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning conditional formatting. I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: How would one go about using conditional formatting (or rather, why would it not suit my needs)? I am fairly new to using Excel, and writing a Macro sounds daunting (though it might not be).

Comment: I've written plenty of macros, but never conditional formatting. @DeanOC might have some advice. (And so would Google! I've learned almost everything I know about Excel by Googling it.)

Comment: Yeah, I've been Googling a bit too. Sometimes I'm just not sure what to use as search terms, haha

Comment: You can actually use the formula in one cell to change the formatting in another cell via conditional formatting. Won't work in every situation, but it can work.

Comment: @guitarthrower I haven't seen that before. Can you provide a link to an example? Google isn't showing any sites with examples.

Comment: Touche' @pnuts. Not the classiest move on my part. I've removed the comment and will recomment with the non-LMGTFY link

Comment: @BrettFromLA take a look at [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) from Microsoft support for ideas.

Comment: @pnuts. I didn't take it like that. Thanks for the link!